# Equal sign in axios data causes axios not to send the correct data object

Tags: javascript, json, axios

i am trying to send the following json object to an REST API.

```
  let json = {
    name: name,
    type: type,
    format: format,
    param: param,
  };
```

With "param","type","format and "name" all beeing strings. I use "=" as a value if the user enters an empty string. (Something my company decided, thats not the point here)

I construct data for the request like this:

```
 let data = JSON.stringify(json);
```

The JSON Object looks the following (when printed out in the console):

```
{"name":"Test","type":"=","format":"=","param":"="}
```

The Problem is that firefox console and the receiving site (the REST API) reports to me, that i send `{"name":"Test","type":"   "\",\"format\":\""` as data which obviously is not what i want to sent.

Since i give axios the correct object and it works correctly if my strings arent equal signs i guess this may be the problem. Is there a way to fix this? Maybe with some encoding? Or with a parameter for axios?

Thanks in advance for your help

I call my axios method in the following way

```
let request = await this.requestAxios(`${this.$root.restURL}interfaces/${this.interfaceDetailId}?languages=${this.$root.language}`,"PATCH",data);
```

My axios Method looks the following:

```
async requestAxios(url, method, data = "", skipPostLog = false) {
    //Prevent a unwanted recursion. Only log when the caller is not log itself

    if (!skipPostLog) {
        await this.log(
            `${method}-Request to endpoint ${url} with data: ${data}`,
            `requestAxios()`,
            "TRACE"
        );
    } else if (
        url !== `${this.$root.restURL}log?language=${this.$root.language}` &&
        skipPostLog
    ) {
        await this.log(`${method}-Request to endpoint ${url}:`, `requestAxios()`, "TRACE");
    }

    let request;
    try {
        request = await axios.request({
            url,
            method,
            data,
            headers: {
                authorization: this.$root.getToken(),
            },
        });
    } catch (e) {
        request = e.response;
    }
    if (request.status === 401) {
        eventBus.$emit("showErrorMessage", request.data.message);
    }
    return request;
},
```

```
curl 'http://localhost:3013/v1/interfaces/1?languages=de' -X PATCH -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'authorization: 37ea8c25a695da1ff6afe7b3dbf1ad87' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --data-raw '{"name":"Test","type":"=","format":"=","param":"="}'
```

Comment: share your code, I don't think you use axios the right way. You don't need to handle serialization yourself.

Comment: Where and how are you constructing `data`…?

Comment: Sorry i missed to add that. Its now in there

Comment: To put it bluntly: the first instinct here is to assume you have a typo somewhere and are *actually* creating `data` as `{name: "Test", type: '   ","format":"'}` or something like that. You'll need to provide *really* convincing evidence that this is not actually the case and we can be 100% certain that the problem is either in `JSON.stringify` (unlikely) or `axios` (also pretty unlikely). It would also help to know where exactly you're reading that mangled data from. What does the browser's network inspector report is actually being sent?

Comment: Wenn i add an console.log(data) is shows me data as `{"name":"Test","type":"=","format":"=","param":"="}` which is exactly what i want. And the rest of the code you see there.
The data is read from a vue.js UI. It reads it correctly as empty strings which i replace with an equal sign

Or how do you want evidence?

Comment: What does the browser's developer tool's network inspector show as the data being sent in the request?

Comment: It says `{"name":"Test","type":"=","format":"=","param":"="}` when i view it as unformatted. And `{"name":"Test","type":" "\",\"format\":\""` in formatted mode.

Comment: So the *raw data* being sent is correct? Then the issue is not with axios or anywhere client-side… Maybe you're missing the correct `Content-Type` header and the server is trying to treat the value as form-encoded?

Comment: Yes. When i ask firefox to give it to me as a CURL Statment its gives me a statment with correct raw data. (see in the post. i added it there)

So yes it most likely is the server-side if i now see this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're serialising the data yourself and are passing a string to axios, everyone—including your server probably—is apparently assuming the data is a form-encoded string. You either need to add a `header`:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

*or* you pass an object, not a string, to axios so it'll do all that for you.

Comment: Sadly this solution does not solve my problem. 
When i add the header it behaves just the same. Firefoxs Network Inspector shows that i added the content type header but when i let firefox give me the curl command it shows

x-www-form-urlencoded

as Content type.

When i give axios an object it is the same behavior in the end

Comment: Okay i just looked what the server acutally recieved now. And it shows
`TRACE:  2021-10-01T08:42:04.421231+0200 – received request body:   {"name":"Test","type":"=","format":"=","param":"="}`

So it gets correctly to the API. My problem lies in the api. So very much thank you for you help. As now at least the correct thing goes to my API!